# Pulp modeling a problem using list of LP variables

Tags: python, pulp

I am trying to solve the following problem.

https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/9298/how-to-build-a-deterministic-optimization-model-for-the-following-fc

we have $x_1,x_2,...,x_365$ are the order shipped from an FC to a customer for 365 days
We have  $o_1,..,o_365$ the amount that we ship from the DC to the FC.
We have the parameter $d1,d2,d3,...,d365$ is the the demand for the day.

We have $l_1,l_2,l_3,l_4,l_5,...,l_365$ is the lost sales for the day.

We also have $I_1,I_2,I_3,...,I_(365)$ is the inventory stored in the FC.

I have the following definition for my lost sales

$l_i=d_i-x_i$

and we have inventory
is

$I_1=50-x_1$ starting iventory is 50

$I_2=i_1-x_2+o1$

$i_3=i_2-x3+o2$

$i_4=i_3-x_4+o_2$ [take 1 day for an order to reach ]

$i_365=i_{364}-x_{365}+o_{362}$

Problem is I am not sure how to code this in python pulp.

I have the following objective function I want to minimize
$50(x_1+..+x365)+2(o_1+...+o_365$)+3(ls_1+...+l_365)+1(o_1+..+o_365$)

I got final which is a csv file
which shows how much I ordered for the 365 days of the year. It is where I get my demand.

But my model return all the zeroes and this cannot be right because my lost sales constraint is not satisfied.

```
days    orders
1       0
2      4
3     1
4    4
5    0
6   1
7   2
8   0
9        5
10       2
11      5

mport pandas as pd 
from pulp import LpMaximize, LpProblem, LpStatus, lpSum, LpVariable,LpMinimize,LpInteger
from pulp import LpBinary
from pulp import LpSolverDefault
import pulp 





k3=pd.read_csv("final.csv")
w2=k3["orders"]
demandStore=w2.tolist()


#DAY shipped 
#WE HAVE ONE DAY MAY HAVE MULTIPLE ORDERS
xArray=[]

    
model = LpProblem(name="small", sense=LpMinimize)


xs = [LpVariable("xs{}_var".format(i+1),lowBound=0,upBound=50, cat="Integer") for i in range(0,365)]  

#ORDERS
os=  [LpVariable("os{}_var".format(i+1),lowBound=0,upBound=50, cat="Integer") for i in range(0,365)] 

#lost sale
ls=  [LpVariable("ls{}_var".format(i+1),lowBound=0,upBound=50, cat="Integer") for i in range(0,365)] 


#inventory
iv=[LpVariable("iv{}_var".format(i+1),lowBound=0,upBound=50, cat="Integer") for i in range(0,365)]

k=[]
#we have here the lost sales 


for i in range(0,365):
#lost sales constraint is demand-orders
   w=ls[i]==demandStore[i]-xs[i]
   k.append(w)
for i in range(0,365):
    model+=k[i]
   
    
cons1=iv[0]==50-xs[0]
cons2=iv[1]==iv[0]-xs[1]+os[0]
cons3=iv[2]==iv[1]-xs[2]+os[1]
model+=cons1
model+=cons2
model+=cons3
k2=[]
for i in range(0,365):
    cool2=xs[i]<=iv[i]
    k2.append(cool2)
for i in range(0,365):
    model+=k2[i]
k3=[]
for i in range(3,365):
    cool=iv[i]==iv[i-1]-xs[i]+os[i-1]
    k3.append(cool)
for i in range(0,362):
    model+=k3[i]
    




One=pulp.lpSum([50*xs[i]+2*os[i]+60*ls[i]+1*iv[i] for i in range(0,365)])
#Two=pulp.lpSum([os[i]*2 for i in range(0,365)])
#Three=pulp.lpSum([iv[i]*1 for i in range(0,365)])
#four=pulp.lpSum([ls[i]*30 for i in range(0,365)])
model+=One
#model+=Two
#model+=Three
#model+=four
model.solve()
#model.solve()
name=[]
value=[]
for var in model.variables():
    print(var.name, " ",var.value())
    name.append(var.name)
    value.append(var.value())
```

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34764209/pulp-solvers-pulpsolvererror-pulp-cannot-execute-glpsol-exe? I wonder if related. Would be helpful to know if you could solve a trivial problem - i.e. is the issue with your solver or your problem formulation.

Comment: I was able to get rid of the glp problem but now my model returns all zero which cannot be right.

Comment: Just to confirm - what is the value of `model.status` after you try to solve the problem? We expect it to be `1` if a solution was found.

Comment: I got a -1 for model status

Comment: I think I got it seems to work if I remove the upper bound of my orders